# how to optimize Bgp Anycast AS path length

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

The question as following:
I have 3 Pop points, they have the same IP address and located at different countries, such as: `USA, Japan, England`. The tree countries serves the whole world web users. We hope all of USA area requests go to USA pop point, all of Japan area goes to Japan pop point and all of European area requests go to England pop points.

but the reality is not, we found some Japan requests go to England, and some USA requests go to Japan.

So now, I can do is to add a number to AS path for the three points(routers). For example if I add 1 to USA, add 3 to Japan and add 5 to England. Then there would be fewer requests go to England, and more requests go to USA, because England become longer and USA become shorter. But it might cause the European requests also left England and go to USA.

So I'm wondering if there is a good algorithm for this problem. And actually I have 20 pop points in the reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically achieved with BGP communities instead of BGP as-path prepending (precisely because of the problem you pointed out yourself).

See, for example, the sections

- Customers wanting to alter their route announcements to selected peers.
- For further granularity, here are additional bgp communities customers can use to alter their route announcements to other NTT Communications BGP customers or peers, as indicated in the descriptions

in the following document:

https://www.us.ntt.net/support/policy/routing.cfm

PS: This question would be more at home at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: hi Bruno, thank you so much! Using community is a good idea, but we need fine granularity tuning, for example ,if England got too much traffic we might grab some traffic from England to USA. So I'm afraid that if I use community policy it may cause either 100% go to USA or 100% goto England, any ideas please?

Comment: To keep the example simple, say you have only two POPs: POP-Europe and POP-America. You want POP-Europe to serve all Europe traffic and no America traffic. You want POP-America to service all America traffic and no Europe traffic. You could make POP-Europe advertise the community which means "Don't advertise to any peer in America" (2914:4029 in the NTT example) and you could make POP-America advertise the community which means "Don't advertise to any peer in Europe" (2914:4229 in the NTT example). If you want the POP-America to be a backup for POP-Europe then use 2914:4223 (prepend) instead